# Turn SQL value to variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

so I have a database table with some user information, like ID, username, etc. and I have been trying to turn a value, for example, Bob's ID into a variable `$id` from the table. This is what I have right now:

```
$db = mysqli_connect(THIS WORKS FINE AND CONTAINS SECRET INFO :));
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM users WHERE username='$prompt'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
```

and I need to turn it into a variable, because I am combining everything into a sentence so it could be `$username has the id of $id`. Thanks

Comment: var_dump $result to see what it is, then figure out how to extract the data you need from it.

Comment: this might also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617824/result-mysql-query

Comment: @Andrew This is what I got: object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.use `sprintf()`.The `sprintf()` function writes a formatted string to a variable.

```
$db = mysqli_connect(THIS WORKS FINE AND CONTAINS SECRET INFO :));
$sql = "SELECT ID,username FROM users WHERE username='$prompt'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$sentence = sprintf("%s has the id of %u.",$row['username'],$row['ID']);

echo $sentence;
```

For more see [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: Just curious, but will it work if I just echo, for example, `$row['username']`?

Comment: `["num_rows"]=> int(1)` means there is only one row.so `$row['username']` will print username fetched from database.

Comment: If you're going to `echo` it anyway, just use [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php).

Comment: @ tadman  yes i aggred with you.But op wants `to turn it into a variable`